# php imagecopyresampled - image is empty (all black) after saving it

Tags: php, image, file, resize

This script will load an image (jpg, gif or png) and then save a PNG local copy for caching.

I'm trying to find a way to resize the image to 300x300 before saving it as a PNG.

I tried to use the function imagecopyresampled() but the image is still not resized.

2 problems now :

- The script saves a resized PNG image in the correct folder, but the image is empty (it's all black)
- The first time i will load the image, i will get an error (image cannot be displayed because it contains error) but the image will still be saved as PNG in the cache folder. Second time i load the image, it will be displayed correctly (using the cached version) but it isn't resized.

Here's the full code of my page. The first part is used to cache the image, the second part is used to display the non-cached image (it reads an image from a ZIP file and output the content without extracting anything)

```
if (empty($_GET['display'])) {
header('Content-Type: image/png');

            $imgpochette = $_GET['i'];

            $ENABLE_CACHE = true;
            $CACHE_TIME_HOURS = 744;
            $CACHE_FILE_PATH = "pochette_album/$imgpochette.png";

            if($ENABLE_CACHE && file_exists($CACHE_FILE_PATH) && (time() - filemtime($CACHE_FILE_PATH) < ($CACHE_TIME_HOURS * 60 * 60))) {
              echo @file_get_contents($CACHE_FILE_PATH);
            } else {
                    // Load the requested image
                    $imgdisplay = "http://www.pirate-punk.com/pochette.php?i=$imgpochette&display=1";
                    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imgdisplay));
$width = "30";
$height = "30";
list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($CACHE_FILE_PATH);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
                    // Send the image
                    imagepng($new_image, $CACHE_FILE_PATH);
                    exit();
              @file_put_contents($CACHE_FILE_PATH, $output);
              echo $output;
            }

}







if (!empty($_GET['display'])) {
        function showimage($zip_file, $file_name) {
            $z = new ZipArchive();
            if ($z->open($zip_file) !== true) {
                echo "File not found.";
                return false;
            }

            $stat = $z->statName($file_name);
            $fp   = $z->getStream($file_name);
                // search for a path/to/file matching file, returning the index of it
                $index = $z->locateName($file_name, ZipArchive::FL_NOCASE|ZipArchive::FL_NODIR);
                // get the name of the file based on the index
                $full_file_name = $z->getNameIndex($index);
                // now get the stream
                $fp = $z->getStream($full_file_name);

            if(!$fp) {
                echo "Could not load image.";
                return false;
            }

            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $stat['size']);
            fpassthru($fp);
            return true;
        }

        $imgsrcencoded = $_GET['i'];
        $imagesrc = base64_decode($imgsrcencoded);
        $explodez = explode("#",$imagesrc);
        $imgg = utf8_encode($explodez[1]);
        $dirnfile = $explodez[0];
        $zipp = end((explode('/', $dirnfile)));
        $dirr = str_replace($zipp,"",$dirnfile);
        $dirr = rtrim($dirr,"/");
        $imgg = rtrim($imgg);
        chdir($dirr);
            if (empty($_GET['debug'])) {
            echo showimage($zipp,$imgg);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the [solution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) for `.png` images

Comment: example with my script please ?